# Where can I host the compiled version of my game for free?

Tags: distribution, hosting

Can somebody recomend a free site for distributing and advertising my freeware (but *not* open source) Asteroids game in BINARY format?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by repository?

Comment: Hi, something like source forge. I was going to use it, but currently my project is not Open Source.

Comment: Why would you need a repository for a binary game? Repos are for source code. Are you just asking for cloud storage?

Comment: What's wrong with just traditional web hosting?

Comment: No. I'm not currently looking for cloud strorage. Just a means to distribute a desktop game. Actually, all I need is hosting. Free, no ad hosting would do the trick.

Comment: I'd suggest MegaUpload, but...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desura are fairly good for Indies - even free. They do have an approval process though, but it's more for the purpose of checking that you're uploading an actual game, and the one that you describe, and that it's not Copyright infringing, and that it works.

I haven't put any on there myself yet, so I can't testify as to how easy or well it works.

**Source**:
http://www.desura.com/development

Answer (score 3):

If it's for windows, you could host with either http://en.softonic.com/windows/games or http://www.bluesnap.com/ecommerce/sellers/digital-sales/sell-games

Both are solutions that will get you users and will also take care of payment.

Answer (score 2):

It may not be exactly what you asked, but I think [Gamejolt](http://gamejolt.com/) would work. You can upload desktop games there.

Comment: I'll take a look at this, thanks. The game needs some more work done on it. In the meantime I want to distribute to friendly beta testers without e-mailing them a large zip file!

Comment: If you're distributing to a small group, you can just use something like Dropbox. Otherwise it looks like CrociDBs suggestion works.

Comment: hmm. Registered with GameJolt a few hours ago but have not received the all important verification e-mail.